# CSS in JSF templating

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2

I am seeing CSS template examples in JSF. For example,

In search.css:

```
#search {    
    color: #00cc66; 
}
```

In index.xhtml:

```
<ui:define name="search">
            <h:messages />
...
</ui:define>
```

So the search.css will apply to the "search" section defined in index.xhtml. But what exact html tags do the search.css apply to in the defined search section on a page? "search" is not a html tag. I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

CSS runs in web browser.

JSF runs in web server, producing HTML output.

CSS does not see server side source code.

CSS only sees HTML DOM tree.

For CSS, JSF is just a HTML code generator.

Right click page in browser and do *View Page Source* or *Inspect Element*.

Write your CSS based on *that* HTML.

Comment: Thanks. I was wrong. the css doesn't really apply to the define "search", but applies to a <div id="search"> tag. Since both places use the same name, i got confused.